# Phonegap: iFrames and external URLs

Tags: ios, iframe, jquery-mobile, cordova, external-url

I am in the process of creating an iOS app with Phonegap and jQuery, however, I am running into issues trying to allow both iFrames (to load normally) and external URLs (to open in Safari).  I decided to choose the path of using iframes as I was not able to send POST and open the resulting page in Safari (i was trying to create a mobile friendly login window that opens to the full site in safari).

I recently updated to v1.5 hoping to resolve the issue, but it still occurs.

I have tried the trick "[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"...." however this forces any page in the iframe to load in safari.

So, I would like either to have external URLs and iframes to behave just like it does in a Webapp (add to homescreen button on iOS) or be able to send POST to Safari?

Has anyone got ideas? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could change tactic slightly and login fully using your app, but then create an authentication token which would be passed via a standard link to be opened in safari.

You could generate the token new each time.  Tokens are a valid system for access.